# OBIEE generated query using irrelevant fact tables in its select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, obiee

In an analysis, we are counting number of all loaned items by their interest rate. It uses one fact table F1 and three dimension tables D1, D2 and D3.  F1 is joined to all these three dimension tables. Therefore, as I see it there shouldn't be any complicated query generated to get the result.

However, when running the analysis, counts are returning 0s. In database, I looked at physical queries generated for this analysis and saw that two selects are being created and another fact table F2 is being used in 2nd select.

Strange thing is that F2 is not used in an analysis, its columns are not selected in criteria tab, no LTS exists to this table from F1, D1,D2 or D3. One thing that is common is that this F2 is also joined to D1, D2 and D3. But why use F2 in query if it is not selected in analysis, do you have any ideas?

Here is what we have in BMM:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the case then you have a situation where as per your model both facts can fulfill the needs of the analysis. Your model is probably not explicit enough.

Have you set an implicit fact column on the subject area to force F03 over F02? Note that it is only possible to set one implicit fact column per subject area.

If you really want to solve the issue rather than work around it you must make sure your model is explicit in terms of which fact to use for which query.

Also: If this is your BMM layer then one suggestion: Use correct business names and designations! Seeing something like "CAL_DAY" will have business users wondering whether they're facing some kind of 1980's tech managed by quite outdated staff ;)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. This cleared out some confusing understandings on using multiple fact columns in one subject area. Regarding implicit fact columns, I have not set an implicit fact column on the subject area. Haven't tried it yet, but I think this will force using F03 over F02 giving a correct results. But before doing this, I wanted to ask what are teh ways to make the model more explicit. After some research I found that F2 has no need to join to D3 , so will eliminating the join make it more explicit?

Comment: Also : You are right, names may be confusing. I was working on the already existing repository, so right now main focus is being given on getting results correct in presentation, I am thinking of changing business names right after getting rid of this kind of errors

Comment: P.S. Removed unnecessary join between F2 and D3,  analysis is giving correct results now. This was the case when one join was not needed, but in case when all joins are needed, I think setting an implicit fact column should be done as you said